# is there any Elasticsearch operations close to MongDB projection?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-6

i imported my mongodb into elasticsearch for doing some complex sorting, a part of it looks like this

```
{
    "ProductName": {
        "WORLDWIDE": {
            "zh": "产品 1",
            "en": "product 1"
        },
        "CHINA": {
            "zh": null,
            "en": null
        }
    }
}
```

in Mongodb's aggregation i can use

```js
$project: {
    "ProductName": {
        $ifNull: [ {$ifNull: [ "$ProductName.CHINA.zh", "$ProductName.CHINA.en" ]}, {$ifNull: [ "$ProductName.WORLDWIDE.zh", "$ProductName.WORLDWIDE.en" ]} ]
    }
}
```

to get the specific value into one a field without nested.

is it possible to do the same thing in elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with the below [Script Fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html) where I've created a new variable `my_productName` and assigned the values as per the condition you've mentioned in the mongo aggregation query.

Note that I'm assuming the fields are of type [`keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) otherwise it is not possible using [text](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html) datatype. Feel free to change the condition in below query as its self-explainable.

Also I'm assuming that all of your documents would be having any one of the values as mentioned in the same document in your question.

### Query Request:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "script_fields" : {
        "my_productName" : {
            "script" : {
                "lang": "painless",
                "source": """
                if(doc['ProductName.CHINA.zh'].value!=null){
                  return doc['ProductName.CHINA.zh'].value;
                }else if(doc['ProductName.CHINA.en'].value!=null){
                  return doc['ProductName.CHINA.en'].value;
                }else if(doc['ProductName.WORLDWIDE.zh'].value!=null){
                  return doc['ProductName.WORLDWIDE.zh'].value;
                }else {
                  return doc['ProductName.WORLDWIDE.ch'].value;
                }

                """
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Query Response:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "<your_index_name>",
        "_type" : "<your_type_name>",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "fields" : {
          "my_productName" : [
            "产品 1"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

One more thing is if you want other fields to appear you can add 
`"_source": {"fieldname1", "fieldname2}` on top of the `"query"`.

Hope this helps and if it does, feel free to upvote and/or accept the answer :)

Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: Sure, do keep me posted. Happy to help!!